# What's the proper way to write CMakeLists.txt to statically link a target with secondary dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, static-linking

First, I think the question title is mostly-accurate, but please let me know how to change it if I'm not asking correctly.

I've got an executable I want to use, specifically [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform). There are great instructions on that readme.md for how to build this *dynamically*. **However, my deployment requires that I statically link the target** so as to avoid installing the dependencies before use. How do I accomplish this?

audiowaveform depends on a couple of things, according to readelf:

```
$ readelf -d ~/Desktop/audiowaveform

Dynamic section at offset 0x4dd78 contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsndfile.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgd.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmad.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libid3tag.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_regex.so.1.58.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.58.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Great. All of those are included in CMakeLists.txt with `find_package(x)` and so on. The only libs not explicitly included are libstdc++, libm, libgcc_s, and libc, which are I guess special standard libraries and automatically available? (I would love clarity here too, though it's not my question.)

Since I want a statically linked output, it seems straightforward to me to modify CMakeLists.txt to find the static versions of these libraries, by adding something like `SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")` above the `find_package()` statements.

The problem is, those libraries themselves have many dynamic dependencies. If I do simply this, those secondary dependencies are unresolved, and the linker chokes with a bunch of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libid3tag.a(util.o): In function 'id3_util_compress':
(.text+0x2a9): undefined reference to 'compress2'` and so on and so forth for days.

I think I know how to find the entire list of dependencies in order, with `ldd`:

```
$ ldd ~/Desktop/audiowaveform
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd057f000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f748288d000)
    libgd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3 (0x00007f7482621000)
    libmad.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmad.so.0 (0x00007f7482401000)
    libid3tag.so.0 => /usr/lib/libid3tag.so.0 (0x00007f74821e8000)
    libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f7481f6a000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f7481d51000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f7481a49000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f7481845000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f74814c2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f74811b9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7480fa3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7480bd9000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f7480964000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f74806bb000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f7480461000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7480247000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f7480022000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f747fd77000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f747fb34000)
    libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0x00007f747f922000)
    libvpx.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3 (0x00007f747f4fd000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f747f289000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f747f06c000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f747ec09000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f747e875000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005567e9b26000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f747e66b000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f747e43f000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f747e215000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f747dedb000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f747dcb9000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f747daab000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f747bff3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f747bdef000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f747bbcc000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f747b9c8000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f747b7c2000)
```

I BELIEVE, if I manually write that entire list of dependencies into CMakeLists.txt, writing FindX.cmake modules as I go, that will satisfy all the secondary, tertiary, etc etc dependencies. But surely there must be a faster way; one that automatically satisfies secondary dependencies of specified static libraries, right?

What's the best way to go about satisfying the entire dependency tree while statically linking a target with CMake?

Comment: `But surely there must be a faster way; one that automatically satisfies secondary dependencies of specified static libraries, right?` - Unlike to dynamic libraries, static ones don't have a list of required libraries, so there is **no direct way** for collect all indirect dependencies automatically. And CMake cannot help with that. One may **guess**, that static libraries are named like a shared ones, but this is not always true.

Comment: No direct way, sure, but then could one not take the output of ldd, assume .a static libraries exist for all of the dynamic ones, and error in the case more manual intervention was required? Surely that'd do the business in most cases. Am I just totally off the mark about how frequent a problem this is that it seems like basic and useful functionality?